# Command has different output when running in a shell or in script

Tags: adb, shell, scripts

I'm trying to run a script on the [Nox emulator](https://www.bignox.com/) through adb. After connecting to Nox via adb with `adb connect localhost:62001` and copying a script into a `/data/scripts/script.sh` folder, executing it gives me different outputs. The script contains the following:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
dd if="/data/scripts/screen.dump" bs=4 skip=540503 count=1 | hd

# Expected output: 00000000  08 04 1D FF
```

Now, here is the problem: I'm getting different results depending where/how I run the script. For it to work, I need to open the shell first with `adb shell`, and any of the following commands work from within it:

- `dd if="/data/scripts/screen.dump" bs=4 skip=540503 count=1 | hd`
- `. ./data/scripts/script.sh`

But I need to be able to run the commands from within a script without having to type them. All of these **don't** work:

- `adb shell sh ./data/scripts/script.sh`
- `adb shell . ./data/scripts/script.sh`
- `adb shell 'dd if="/data/scripts/screen.dump" bs=4 skip=540503 count=1 | hd'`

The main error I'm getting is `Usage: hd [-b base] [-c count] [-r delay] file` (which is weird because I know it's correct), and occasionally also `dd: stdout: Broken pipe`. I've spent about 5 hours today trying only to solve this and I'm out of ideas... If anyone has one let me know!

Comment: `adb shell` cannot access directories in `/data/` without root access. Are you running with root privileges? What's the ownership of `/data/scripts`? What's SELinux status?

Comment: @IrfanLatif I'm not sure if I'm answering your question correctly, but running `ls -ld /data` gave me back `system`.

Comment: What's the output of `adb shell id`, `adb shell ls -l /data/scripts` and `adb shell getenforce`? From where did you get `hd` binary? Did you try `hexdump`?

Comment: 1. `uid=0(root) gid=0(root)` (I've shortened the output)
2. All of them are `root`
3. `getenforce` is `Disabled`
4. I have BusyBox installed under `/xbin`, and I just tested using `hexdump` instead of `hd` and it worked... Why though?

Comment: For anyone working with `hd`, take care that replacing it with `hexdump` won't return the same results as `hd`! Instead use `hexdump -C`, more about it [here](https://superuser.com/a/827508).